# Inserting DBNull in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Is there a way to send DBNull value to MS Access SQL from VBA?

I tried the following:

```
Me.ShortDate.Value = ""
Me.ShortDate.Value = vbNull
Me.ShortDate.Value = Null
```

but the Insert/Update query updates it to

```
ShortDate =
```

And Hence I get an error: Syntax Error in Update Statement
How Can I insert Null fields in MS Access through VBA? Is there nothing like DBNull in VBA?

Comment: Leave the column name/value out of the insert/update statement if you don't want to insert a value for that field.

Comment: Is this in the VBA behind a userform? Do you have a relevant update query in your code that you did not post here? Is ShortDate actually a Date field in the database or is it just a text field where you are storing a date?

Answer (score -1):

**ShortDate** is a Date Field and Reserve Word in MS-Access and using these type of reserve keywords is not a good practice.

Change your field Name like **txtShortDate** and then try with Null.